# Simple .is() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through images, and if the last image has a class of `.active`, I start again. However, it is not working at all:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/VE75U/

```
img.click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active').next('img').addClass('active');
    if ($('.active').is(':last-child')) {  
       img.first().addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if the last image has the class `.active` you have to almost reverse it and first get the last image and then check for the class, and since the last-child isn't an image, that wont work

```
if ( $('.module.m-slide img:last').hasClass('.active') ) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I do that, and it loops. However, it breaks the slideshow: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/VE75U/11/ Would you know why?

Comment: Your slideshow isn't working at all for me, so I really have no idea ?

Comment: Sorry, when you click on the image (not dots) it does not work?

Comment: Oh, okay. That's not at all how I would solve that, I'd do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/VE75U/14/

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues in your code:

When you click on last image this code:

```
$(this).removeClass('active').next('img').addClass('active');
```

Will not add `active` class to anything, because `.next('img')` will return an empty array. So next line will not work too:

```
if ($('.active').is(':last-child'))
```

Because there is no active elements.

I believe you need to fix it in the following way:

```
if ($(this).is(':last-child'))
```

Next thing: none of your images can be a `:last-child`, because even your last image is not a last child! Look carefully at your html code:

```
<div class="module m-slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x800&text=1" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x800&text=2" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x800&text=3" alt="" />
    <div class="m-slide-ctrl"></div>
</div>
```

Your last child is `<div class="m-slide-ctrl"></div>`

I suggest to change it in the follosing way:

```
<div class="module m-slide">
    <div class="m-slide-ctrl"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x800&text=1" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x800&text=2" alt="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x800&text=3" alt="" />
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VE75U/13/)